# Merge 'led' and 'notification-led'?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request, tag-cleanup

Again I stumbled upon two synonymously used tags. [led](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/led) (x14) is a little misleading (as it also might refer to the "led flash"), but all of the questions refer to the [notification-led](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/notification-led) (x3).

My suggestions:

1. merge 'led' into 'notification-led'
2. make 'led' a synonym to 'notification-led'

Number 2. might need discussion in case there are arguments concerning led-flash.

Comment: It looks like there actually are a few referring to the camera's LED flash. I see 3 right now: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/32938/whats-the-purpose-of-strobe-frequency-adjustment-in-torch, http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26168/how-to-make-front-lamp-intependent-from-photo, http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1819/any-concerns-using-led-flashlight-apps. It does seem like a good idea to disambiguate `led`.

Comment: Oh -- I thought I saw them at first, but could not find them later, so I edited this out of my original question. As the edit does not appear as such, I cannot roll-back: #0 should then have "re-tagging those to `camera-flash` (Done). I will do so now. Thanks for bringing them up!

Comment: How can a tag be disambiguated? I had that in mind as well, but a tag is a tag: we either can 1) make it a synonym, 2) blacklist it, 3) ignore it, or 4) watch it and continuously re-tag. To me, 2+3 are no real options, and 4 is hard to practice (unless registering as a follower)...

Comment: Synonymizing is, to me, a form of disambiguation, since you then know that `led` specifically refers to whatever the synonym is (in this case, `notification-led` makes sense).

Comment: OK -- so let's do it? I re-tagged the flashlight stuff, so all is ready for a merge. Also, would you be so kind to investigate my previous 4 tag-cleanup requests? They hang around for about 3 days now almost unnoticed ;)

Comment: I'll take a peek real quick, though I'm getting ready to leave work in ~15 minutes so any actual merging might wait until I actually get home a little later tonight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I merged [led](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/led) into [notification-led](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/notification-led) and made the latter one the master.

Comment: Thanks! So I just added the tag wiki for the new master, also pointing out that "torch" and "LED flash" should use the `camera-flash` tag instead.